# HtmlUnit: Check whether the HtmlElement is HtmlAnchor

Tags: htmlunit

I have a HtmlElement.

The HtmlElement is sometimes a table/cell/etc and sometimes it is an anchor link.

How can I check whether the HtmlElement is an HtmlAnchor or not?

The only way I can think of is to cast the HtmlElement to HtmlAnchor and see whether it results in a ClassCastException. This is not a good coding standard since I have unused variable `anchorLink`

```
   final HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlPage.getFirstByXPath(String.format("//*[text()='%s']", "textName"));
   try {
     HtmlAnchor anchorLink = (HtmlAnchor) htmlElement;
     System.out.println("HtmlElement is an anchor link!");
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
     System.out.println("HtmlElement is not an anchor link!");
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to check if the obtained element is an anchor.
Adapting your code would result in something like

```
final HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlPage.getFirstByXPath(String.format("//*[text()='%s']", "textName"));

if (htmlElement instanceof HtmlAnchor) {
    System.out.println("HtmlElement is an anchor link!");
} else {
    System.out.println("HtmlElement is NOT an anchor link!");
}
```

As a side note, I recomend using simple `String` concatenation:

```
String text = "textName";
final HtmlElement htmlElement = htmlPage.getFirstByXPath("//*[text()=" + text + "]");
```